# Disable DocumentFilter on Document (JTextArea) temporarily?

Tags: java

How can I disable a DocumentFilter on a JTextArea just temporarily?

```
((AbstractDocument)area1.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(dec);
```

The filter introduces some behavior that I need to get rid of.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just do ((AbstractDocument)area1.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(null); and then reset it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
((AbstractDocument)area1.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new MyFilter());

class MyFilter extends DocumentFilter{

}
```

create your own customFilter which will do nothing.

Comment: Will the effect be the same if I set it to null and restore it afterwards?

Comment: i followed this way , i'm not sure about the output if passed null,maybe you should try both

Comment: appreciate if you post the output too